# Set layout width and height programmatically base on Screen size Android

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

I have a some problem with my `layout` when my screen change from `portrait` to `landscape` mode.

**issues I'm facing**

I have a `SquareLayout` `widget` which extends a `LinearLayout`, which help me to make a perfect square, and that work fine just as I want it to in `portrait` mode but if I change the from the `orientation` to `landscape` the square will be  small, I want to be able to get the same size in `Landscape` mode and there I will have a `scrollView` to help with the height.

1) How to get the size of the screen and base on that set the `layout` `width` and `height` programmatically.

2) If I can get the size of the square in `portrait` mode and pass it to my `landscape` square, In that case I think the `width` will be fine and if i put a `scrollView` the user can be `scroll` for the full height.

**The reason I'm more concerned about this is because of android device screen size, That is why I want to know the size of the screen and base on that set the width and height.**

Answer (score 1):

You can do as suggested above programmatically, or you could just create a new folder for your layouts called layout-land and then create the same layout you want just for landscape and then it will auto change to the new layout when the device is flipped.

More info can be found here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Answer (score 0):

From within activity:

```
int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

From Non Activity Class in which you have context of activity

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
int width = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int height = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [w9jds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2034672/w9jds) :
If you need the landscape layout to be different than the portrait layout, you need to make a `layout-land` folder in the `res` folder. Now you can make two different xml files w.r.t orientation for the same screen. Just Make sure that they both have the same names. Make the landscape one with the `ScrollView` and the portrait one without the `ScrollView`. Calculate the width and height of the square in the same manner for both layouts.

For more Information about multiple layouts in android, read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article.